# error 0xc0000142 when debug with visual studio 2022 and Windows Terminal

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2022, windows-terminal

I'm using visual studio 2022 on the platform of windows 11 version 22h2. In the current upgrade 22621.675, Windows Terminal became the default terminal of Windows as well as of visual studio 2022. Now, when I debug in vs2022, if I shut down the console window while the program is still running, a window pops out, and reports "Application Unable to Start Correctly (Error: 0xc0000142)", like this:
[image]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("num: %d\n", i);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

If I close the error window, it will pop out again and again even I close the IDE, and the times it pops is equal to the number of the loops in the code. When I restore the default console to cmd.exe, this error doesn't appear anymore.

Anyone can help me fix this error? Because I prefer Windows Terminal to cmd.exe.

After test for dozens of times, I find if I use Ctrl + Pause to stop the application, nothing is wrong. While, if I stop the application by clicking the cross at the right-top corner of the application window, the error 0xc0000142 pops up. So I compiled the test.cpp file into a test.exe application and use *Process Explorer* to analyze the problem.

**Situation 1:**
Open Windows Terminal and drag the test.exe into the terminal window and press "enter" to run test.exe. With *Process Explorer* I can find test.exe is the sub-process of Windows Terminal:
[image]
When I close Windows Terminal by clicking the window, the process tree of Windows Terminal is killed, and everything is ok.

**Situation 2:**
Run test.exe by clicking it. With *Process Explorer* I can notice the processes of Windows Terminal and test.exe are not connected.
[image]
When I close the console window, the error message 0xc0000142 pops up. The process of Windows Terminal is killed, but the process of test.exe still exists.
[image]

I'm wondering what results in the problem and how do I fix it? thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm on the same configuration as you, VS2022 version 17.3.6, but I didn't have this problem, what is the version`22621.675` that you mentioned? Also, the windows terminal is actually a wrapper that opens cmd.exe, I suspect that by closing it, it tried to shut down cmd.exe when it's still running, and cmd.exe rejected to be shut down. When the terminal closed, cmd.exe's StdOut handle became invalid, hence the error

Comment: my Windows version is 22621.675. thank you for your answer, do you have an idea to figure this problem out?

Comment: Can you install [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) and confirm that `cmd.exe` (spawned by `WindowsTerminal.exe`) didn't close after closing the terminal?

Comment: @thedemons I try to use Process Explorer to inspect the process and I find if the debug is over correctly the processes of Windows Terminal and cmd.exe will be both closed. While, if the debug console is closed in running, the process of Windows Terminal is closed, but the process of cmd.exe still exist.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like `cmd.exe` reject to be closed, can you try to create a new profile that opens a `.bat` file that will run `cmd.exe`, set that profile as the default profile for windows terminal, and see what would happen?

Comment: I create a .bat file and type "cmd" in it. I open Windows Terminal and run the .bat file to enter cmd. when I close Windows Terminal everything is ok. the error doesn't occur.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can post an answer and mark it as accepted, for other people who have a similar problem.

Comment: @thedemons sorry my problem is not solved yet. if I don't run cmd by visual studio debugger, everything is ok. while if i debug with Windows Terminal and interrupt the debugging program the error 0xc0000142 will still occur. I find the program seems not to "know" Windows Terminal is shut down by person, so the program doesn't stop. when the program "moves forward", it finds Windows Terminal is already closed, so the error message "Application Unable to Start Correctly (Error: 0xc0000142)" pops out. I'm not very good at computer, what I guess might incorrect.

Comment: @thedemons the only solution I can think of is to restore the default console to cmd.exe

Comment: I think the problem is that the windows terminal doesn't force close the cmd.exe, it just ask it to close. Or, the cmd.exe is attached to the debugger and the windows terminal didn't have enough permission to open its handle to terminate it. Can you try to run VS as administrator to see what would happen?

Comment: I tried run VS as administrator and I found that VS wouldn't call Windows Terminal to run the code even if I set Windows Terminal as the default terminal application.  Finally, I find a compromise solution to avoid this problem. that is to interrupt the running program by use Crtl + Pause keys rather than to use mouse click.@thedemons